# MySQL Fulltext search with order by date, limit, and offset

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying do a fulltext search on a large database with over 100 million rows.
When I do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM LOGS 
WHERE MATCH(message) AGAINST('"test"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
AND username = 'john' 
LIMIT 50;
```

I get 50 results in under half a second. However, I would like to get the newest results first, meaning I want to order the results by date. So I tried something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM LOGS 
WHERE MATCH(message) AGAINST('"test"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
AND username= 'john' 
ORDER BY DATE DESC 
LIMIT 50;
```

Considering each user can have millions of logs, this takes well over 5 minutes.

I'm implementing a search function on a web application and I want to get 50 rows at a time with newest logs showing up first, and when you click on `get more logs` I want to get the next 50 results using the offset. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, I realized that there is no way to find an efficient way to get the results in mind with MySQL. The best way is to use a FullText search engine like [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/). I have not implemented Sphinx on my server yet but I believe it should work. If anyone has any other suggestions feel free to let me know in comments.

Answer (score 0):

just need to implement Pagination or something like that to get next any (10, 50 etc ) results using the offset.

use this sample code for reference

```
$perPage = 10;

$pageNo = $_GET['page'];
```

Now find total rows in database.

```
$totalRows = Get By applying sql query;

$pages = ceil($totalRows/$perPage);    

$offset = ($pageNo - 1) * $perPage + 1

$sql = "SELECT * FROM XYZ WHERE cdate='18/07/2012' LIMIT ".$offset." ,".$perPage
```

Now this could lead to sql injections so make sure you'll use parameters in  URL as encoded form and use SQL function "mysqli_escape_string" to escape the string injections.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This answer cannot solve my issue. Doing a FullText search on database with 100+ million rows can take a very long time. Please check my answer to this post if you are curious about the solution.